# SEO - Table with links - better with <a>anchor text</a> or wrap entire row in <a> tag?

Tags: seo, hyperlink

I have a table of houses for sale - detailing address, price, size, year of construction, energy rating.

For mobile usability, I've made the entire row as a link - i.e. user can click anywhere in the row.

Will this impact SEO?

I know the text on a link can influence context of the destination page - so wondering if it'd be better just to have the `address` part as link, as having the full row as a link results in the anchor text of:

`123 Street name, county, state 128m2 $150,000 2007`

whereas if linked on address text only:

`123 Street name, county, state`

Comment: On one hand it is unclear to my why it would be more mobile friendly to have the link so much longer. The shorter link is still long enough by to be clickable or tapable. On the other hand it is hard to know the answer to your question about the seo, since the google algorithms are not publicly known in that much detail. Personally I would simply go for the shorter version which seems more logical to me.